# Remove UINavigationBarButton SubView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following method which adds a `MKNumberBadgeView` to the `UINavigationBar` of a `UITableViewController` -

```
-(void)counterBtn{

MKNumberBadgeView *numberBadge = [[MKNumberBadgeView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, -10, 40, 40)];
numberBadge.strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:239.0/255.0 green:117.0/255.0 blue:33/255.0 alpha:0];
numberBadge.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:239.0/255.0 green:117.0/255.0 blue:33/255.0  alpha:1];
numberBadge.shine = NO;
numberBadge.hideWhenZero = YES;
numberBadge.value = _countBtnNo;

NSLog(@"Value of count = %d", _countBtnNo);
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:numberBadge];
```

}

All works fine until I want to change the count value - I have the following function to change the value -

```
- (void)removeBtn{
    NSLog(@"ddd");
            _countBtnNo = 0;
    [self counterBtn];

}
```

But this does nothing - So i'm guessing I need to remove the subview first before re-adding - though there doesnt seem to be a `removeSubview:numberBadge` method - so i'm struggling!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Store a reference to your `numberBadge` in a property:

   ```
   @property(nonatomic, strong) MKNumberBadgeView *numberBadge;
   ```
2. Then initialize it. To remove it, just call

   ```
   [_numberBadge removeFromSuperview];
   ```
3. Alternatively you can just update the value of the counter. No need to remove it.

   ```
   _numberBadge.value = new value;
   ```

Comment: cheesr for your help @reecon